# How to set the custom width and dynamic height based on html in multipage pdf in tcpdf

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Hello I am working on create the pdf from the html using tcpdf as it have options to passed the layout with custom widht and height but i want the width to be fixed but height can be change based on the html content passed in single as well multiple page pdf.

```
$pageLayout = array(3,10);
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/mypdf.php');

    //  or array($height, $width) 
  //  $pdf = new MYPDF('p', 'pt', $pageLayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf = new MYPDF('p', 'in', $pageLayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```